# duplicate bindings

Tags: wpf, multithreading, treeview, bind

Hi have a TreeView which is bind to ObservableCollectionEx collection.
my application is multi-thread and sometimes i see duplicate entries in the TreeView.

my treeView looks like this:

```
<TreeView 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Titles}" 
        Margin="3"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        Style="{StaticResource TreeViewStyle}"
        >
```

and the bind item source is as:

```
ObservableCollectionEx<Title>
```

actually it happens in the Subtitle class which Title owns:

```
ObservableCollectionEx<Subtitle> Subtitles
```

the Titles update occurs through a delegate

```
void Add_Title(object sender, TitleEventArgs e) { _titles.Add(e.Title); }
```

how can i prevent items from being dupe ?

Comment: Please provide the multi-threaded code that populates your items source.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a check to see if the item already exists or not before adding it

```
void Add_Title(object sender, TitleEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (!_titles.Contains(e.Title))
        _titles.Add(e.Title); 
}
```

If the collection could possible be accessed by multiple threads, you'll probably need something to lock the collection while its being modified as well.

Comment: @MattBurland You're right, if the collection could be modified by different threads then something should be put in place to lock the collection while its being modified. I've updated my answer with that, although I'm not sure what code would be used since I can't see how the OP is handling the threading in his question :)